# VB.Net Answer Checker in Quiz

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Please help me solve my problem in quiz checker. I have 4 choices which display in Radio Button. So my problem is after i check my radio button and submit it gives me score on the corresponding question but after i click the submit button again it adds another score on the same question. how can i prevent my checker to add another score on the same question?

Here is my code.

```
Public Sub Check()
    If Check1.Text < 2 And Check2.Text < 2 And Check3.Text < 2 And Check4.Text < 2 Then
        If CorrectAns.Text = CoAnsDB.Text Then
            score = score + 1
        Else
            score = score + 0
        End If
    Else
        score = score + 0
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click
    Call Check()
    'Call CheckerB()
    'Call CheckerC()
    'Call CheckerD()
    MyScore.Text = score.ToString
    BtnSubmit.Enabled = False
    AnsA.Enabled = False
    AnsB.Enabled = False
    AnsC.Enabled = False
    AnsD.Enabled = False
End Sub

  Private Sub AnsA_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AnsA.CheckedChanged
    CorrectAns.Text = "A"

    If AnsA.Checked = True Then
        Check1.Text = Check1.Text + 1
    End If
    BtnSubmit.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub AnsD_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AnsD.CheckedChanged
    CorrectAns.Text = "D"
    If AnsB.Checked = True Then
        Check4.Text = Check4.Text + 1
    End If
    BtnSubmit.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub AnsC_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AnsC.CheckedChanged
    CorrectAns.Text = "C"
    If AnsC.Checked = True Then
        Check3.Text = Check3.Text + 1
    End If
    BtnSubmit.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub AnsB_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AnsB.CheckedChanged
    CorrectAns.Text = "B"
    If AnsB.Checked = True Then
        Check2.Text = Check2.Text + 1
    End If
    BtnSubmit.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Every time you hit the button, clear out/reset the score. I.e. score = 0

Comment: You set the button enabled to false.. So how come you can click it again?

Comment: The submit button become enabled after clicking the next button and previous button.